# Elastic search not get the all of documents in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I have elastic search single node cluster and it has some index.The index contain 6000 or more documents.Document mapping has lot of fields like(30 or more).I can query all of duplicate records in (Kibana dev tool) but i am querying with python result like 10 records or 20 records.What is the reason?

my index and document count

```
yellow open   test_index kjioInpQRAqT3o1LZHI92g   1   2       7652         1267      20.7mb          20.7mb
```

my mapping

```
{
 "settings": {
  "number_of_shards": 1,
  "number_of_replicas": 2 
 },

 "mappings": {
  "test_index" : {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        # MORE 35 FIELDS ....
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.Document has lot of fields.It has 35 fields.I can query in (kibana dev) tool.Query returned 1000 documents for one time.Python elastic search library can't get this count of documents reason is the single document is too large (Document has 35 fields).Then i change the query and i put the useful fields for query result.Now it's work file.

Change your query like this (normal query)

```
`{
   "_source": ["_id","_index", "quote_date", "asset"],
   "query": {
       "match_all": {
       }
   }
}`
```

Change your query like this (aggregation query)

```
` "aggs": {        
  "duplicateDocuments": {        
     "top_hits": {
        "_source": ["_id","_index", "name", "address"],
                    "sort": [{"create_at": { "order": "desc"} } ]                                                                                                                                
                }
            }
   }`
```